# What will be the replacement for arraylist.clone in java?

Tags: java

What would be another way of implementing

```
list2 = (ArrayList<Integer>)list1.clone();
```

Please help.

Comment: `list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(new Integer(12));
    list1.add(new Integer(24));
    list1.add(new Integer(36));
    list1.add(new Integer(48));

    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer integer : list1) {
        list3.add(new Integer(integer.intValue()));
    }
```

Comment: Or use Collections.copy(dest,src);